# Reading an ArrayList stored in a file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, serialization

So I've made a program to store student data in a binary format using serialization. The student data is stored in ArrayList. While fetching data from file I'm not getting the desired output. Can you guys help!!

```
Code 1: For serialization 

public class MainInput implements Serializable {

    private String Name;
    private int rollno;
    private int marks;
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }


}
```

```
Code 2: for storing values in file 

        MainInput si=new MainInput();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no. of students ");
        int list=sc.nextInt();
        while(list>0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the RollNo");
            int r=sc.nextInt();
            si.setRollno(r);
            System.out.println("Enter name ");
            String na=sc.next();
            si.setName(na);
            System.out.println("Enter marks ");
            int m=sc.nextInt();
            si.setMarks(m);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("D:\\StudentReportetc.txt",true);
            ObjectOutputStream Out=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            Out.writeObject(si);
            Out.close();
            fout.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }list--;
    }

}
}
```

```
Code 3: for reading

         ArrayList<StudentInfo> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("D:\\StudentReport.txt");
            ObjectInputStream Oin=new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            namesList = (ArrayList) Oin.readObject();
            Oin.close();
            fin.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         for (StudentInfo stu : namesList) {
                System.out.println(stu);
            }
    }

}
```

```
output:
StudentInfo@5910e440
StudentInfo@6267c3bb
```

And afterward, I've to implement binary tree in order to do fast searching
Implementing couldnt be done unless data is read from  the file

Comment: You need to override the ```toString``` method for ```StudentInfo```

Comment: I've already tried that it still prints the same output

Comment: Can you show how you did it?

Comment: public StudentInfo(String Name,int rollno,int marks) {
  this.Name = Name;
  this.rollno = rollno;
  this.marks = marks;
 }
 public String toString() {
  return "Rollno"+'\''+getRollno +'\''+" Name "+ Name +'\''+ " Marks "+'\''+marks;
   }

Comment: @YuvrajPratapSingh try this: public String toString() { return "MainInput [Name=" + Name + ", rollno=" + rollno + ", marks=" + marks + "]"; }